# Can't maintain same RDP connection despite public IP address being static

Tags: networking, remote-desktop

So I have an VPS set up where I want to maintain the same RDP connection - as supposed to having to redownload the RDP file whenever my VPS shuts down - I have set my Public IP address to static but I still have the same problem.

Why isn't it doing what I tell it to?

Comment: Where are you downloading the RDP file from in the first place? How do the RDP file contents differ if you compare both through a text editor? Are you really connecting to the VPS itself, or are you connecting to the hosting company's "remote console"?

Comment: I'm downloading the RDP from my Azure portal, the way I've always done.